# Default value in querystring using Url rewriting in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I have implemented the URL rewrite code for asp.net 3.5 with global.asax.

Here is the example. www.ABC.com/Content/1/Flowers or www.ABC.com/Content/2/Balloons.

Where "Content" is my page name and "Flowers" and "Balloons" are my category. It is working fine in my case.

Suppose I will not add "1" and "2" in my querystring, my URL will look like this. 
**www.ABC.com/Content/Flowers** or **www.ABC.com/Content/Balloons**.

So If I will not pass any parameter in URL, it will take default values. How can I do the same? Here is my code.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{        
    routes.Add("Products", new Route("{CategoryID}/{name}/{PriceId}/{Colorid}/{ColorName}", new RouteValueDictionary { { "PriceId", "0" }, { "Colorid", "0" }, { "ColorName", string.Empty } }, new WebFormRouteHandler("~/Client/Products.aspx")));
}
```

It is not working, How can I set "PriceId", "Colorid" and "ColorName" as a default parameter?

Thanks in advance.